# Repeated Sampling Without Replacement

Tags: algorithm, r, random, sample

I want to generate 10 random numbers from a population 1:1000, and the code that generate this number is repeated 10 times. I want the sampling to be without replacement such that the intersection between the 10 sets of 10 random numbers is null.

First, if I used sample function in r and set replace to false it doesn't help much and
when I searched online I found a function for doing so called urn, but I can't download package in r. so in short I want to do exactly like the following code:

http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/urn/html/urn.html
but manually instead of using the urn package

I tried the following code but the samples generated aren't unique where I select rows from "data" randomly

```
for(j in 1:10) {
    x=unique(data[,2])
    tr=sample(length(x),0.9*length(x),replace=FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Hypothetically, how do you intend to call the urn function? what arguments?

Comment: Can you show what you tried? Maybe we can figure out what is wrong with your code by `sample`.

Comment: How is it different from `sample(1:1000, 100, replace=FALSE)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking into account @ElKamina's comment you could generate 100 numbers using `sample` and allocate them into a 10 x 10 matrix:

```
matrix(sample(1:1000, 100, FALSE), ncol=10)
```

Comment: With replicate you cannot be sure of getting mutually exclusive list of random numbers, right?

Comment: @ElKamina you're absolutely right

Comment: Since the OP requires that the sets are mutually exclusive, could you modify your solution slightly? Sample 100 numbers first and then reshape it into a matrix of 10X10.

Answer (score 0):

I like the sample 100 values and put them in a 10 by 10 matrix the best, but another option would be to sample the 1st 10 from the full list, then use `setdiff` to compute the set without the 10 already chosen, chose another 10 from that group, use `setdiff` again, etc.

This way may work better if you don't know ahead of time how many samples or how many in each sample, though in those cases you could use `sample` to randomly permute the whole list of 1000, then just pick off groups from the permuted list.